# SQL Select subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, select, join, subquery

I'm a little new to SQL and have come across the following problem.

I have a table with company details on it which is joined to a contact table by an enqID.

Within the contact table, there are 4 different types of contacts which may or may not have an entry.  These are differentiated by a ctcTypID (1 - 4)

I would like to produce a query that has all of the company records on it plus a contact name for each of the 4 different types of contact, all on one row.

I thought I could do this by using subqueries for each of the different contacts but I can't seem to get it to work as I don't know how to write a subquery select clause that references it's parent select clause (if you see what I mean!)

Is this even possible?  As I've mentioned, I'm pretty new to SQL so please try not to mock too much!

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like (assuming you're using SQL Server 2005 and up - unfortunately, you didn't mention that in your original post):

```
SELECT 
   c.CompanyName,
   c1.ctcTypID, c1.ContactName,
   c2.ctcTypID, c2.ContactName,
   c3.ctcTypID, c3.ContactName,
   c4.ctcTypID, c4.ContactName
FROM
   CompanyTable c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   ContactTable c1 ON c.enqID = c1.enqID AND c1.ctcTypID = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   ContactTable c2 ON c.enqID = c2.enqID AND c2.ctcTypID = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   ContactTable c3 ON c.enqID = c3.enqID AND c3.ctcTypID = 3
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   ContactTable c4 ON c.enqID = c4.enqID AND c4.ctcTypID = 4
```

You need to use LEFT OUTER JOINs since there might not be a match, and by doing this, your query will not be awfully fast in terms of performance - but it should hopefully work.

Marc

Comment: Thanks,

I think this will do what I need it to.  I wasn't really sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work. Avoids joining on the contact table multiple times.

```
SELECT 
   CompanyTable.CompanyName,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ContactTable.ctcTypID  = 1 THEN ContactTable.ContactName END) AS ContactName1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ContactTable.ctcTypID  = 2 THEN ContactTable.ContactName END) AS ContactName2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ContactTable.ctcTypID  = 3 THEN ContactTable.ContactName END) AS ContactName3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ContactTable.ctcTypID  = 4 THEN ContactTable.ContactName END) AS ContactName4
FROM CompanyTable,
LEFT JOIN ContactTable 
    ON ContactTable.enqID = CompanyTable.enqID AND ContactTable.ctcTypID  IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY
   CompanyTable.CompanyName
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you're trying to use SQL for something that it is not designed for.
SQL is a language that lets you manipulate and retrieve data, you're trying to use SQL to format the output of the retrieved data as well, and I think that you should not do that:

You should not try to format (putting all contacts on one row f.i.) the data with SQL.
My advice is: just use the most performant SQL-query to retrieve the data from the database, and format the output (put the contacts on the same row) in another language (C#, Delphi, PHP, whathever you're using for your application).

Comment: I think you're being a little harsh.  It is perfectly simple to write this as a single SQL statement, as Marc_S shows.  Indeed it might well be more fiddly to take separate SQL outputs and fit them to the desired layout.

Comment: In this case it is indeed possible with a rather simple sql statement.
However, in other similar cases, I sometimes see people writing a very complex and inefficient query (sometimes with UDF's) to achieve this, so to me, the general rule is: do not format the output using sql).
In this case, the data can be retrieved with one simple SQL with just one join statement and an order by clause, and then the results can be simply formatted.